# ON DELETE CASCADE con Trigger AFTER DELETE

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema a la hora de hacer unas bitacoras para unas tablas y espero que puedan ayudarme.
Imaginemos que tengo una tabla *Abuelo* creada de la siguiente forma:

```
    CREATE TABLE ABUELO{
       IDABUELO INT PRIMARY KEY
    }
```

Y una tabla *Padre*

```
    CREATE TABLE PADRE{
    IDPADRE INT PRIMARY KEY
    IDABUELO INT CONSTRAINT FK_IDABUELO FOREIGN KEY IDABUELO REFERENCES ABUELO(IDABUELO) ON DELETE CASCADE
    }
```

La tabla de *Padre* esta referenciada a la de Abuelo por *IDABUELO*.
Ahora, tambien tengo una tabla *Hijo* declarada de la siguiente forma.

```
   CREATE TABLE HIJO{
    IDHIJO INT PRIMARY KEY
    IDPADRE INT CONSTRAINT FK_IDPADRE  FOREIGN KEY IDPADRE REFERENCES  PADRE(IDPADRE ) ON DELETE CASCADE
    }
```

La cual esta referencia a la de *Padre* por su codigo IDPADRE.
Ademas de estas, tengo unas tablas de bitacora *ABUELO_Log*, *PADRE_Log*, e *HIJO_Log* que tienes los mismos atributos.
Cuando borro una fila de *Abuelo*, al ser ON DELETE CASCADE, se borrarán los *padres* que tengan el codigo referenciado a ese *abuelo*.Y a su vez, se borrarán todos los *hijos* que tenga su codigo referenciado al *padre*.
El problema es hacer un Trigger AFTER DELETE (no puede ser INSTEAD OF) que guarde el registro de la fila borrada en su respectiva tabla de bitacora.
Cuando se borra la fila de *Abuelo*, puedo recuperar los datos borrados desde la tabla temporal DELETED accesible durante el trigger , y tranferir estos datos a la de *ABUELO_Log*.
Pero,¿donde quedan guardados los datos borrados de *Padre* e *Hijo* para recuperarlos y guardarlos en sus respetivas bitacoras?
Acaso se guardan en la misma tabla de DELETED, o se crean varias tablas DELETED segun las tablas borradas?
Se como hacer este problema con un trigger INSTEAD OF, pero el problema requiere de un trigger AFTER.

Answer (score 1):

Cree las tablas como lo indicas en tu planteamiento y luego hice un trigger para cada tabla, y tanto en PADRE como en HIJO se dispara el trigger y respalda las tablas.

Estos son los trigger que cree

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_ABUELO_DELETE] 
ON [dbo].[ABUELO]
AFTER DELETE AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ABUELO_Log
    SELECT *
    FROM   deleted
    ;
END

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_PADRE_DELETE] 
ON [dbo].[PADRE]
AFTER DELETE AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.PADRE_Log
    SELECT *
    FROM   deleted
    ;
END

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_HIJO_DELETE] 
ON [dbo].[HIJO]
AFTER DELETE AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.HIJO_Log
    SELECT *
    FROM   deleted
    ;
END
```

Espero te sea de utilidad

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En vez de utilizar TRIGGERS para el desarrollo de la bitácora, considera la configuración de CDC.

Los TRIGGERS encadenados cuando tengas gran volumen de datos afectarán considerablemente la performance de tu sistema.

Te dejo un link para que lo analices, la configuración es sencilla:

https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hola @Toni. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por contribuir! ¿Podrías explicar brevemente cómo sería la solución, sin la necesidad de ver un link externo para entender de qué se trata? La idea es dejar una respuesta completa dentro dentro del sitio, que pueda beneficiar a futuros lectores.

Comment: Tienes razón que esto es más eficiente, pero esta funcionalidad solo está disponible en la versión Enterprise del SQL Server y en la Developer, para que lo puedas probar en desarrollo.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes capturar las filas modificadas en una tablas desde un trigger de otra tabla, lo que tienes que hacer es **crear un trigger AFTER DELETE para cada tabla**.

Cuando se ejecute el DELETE en la tabla Abuelo este disparará los correspondientes DELETE en las tablas Padre e Hijo y, por lo tanto, se dispararán los triggers AFTER DELETE que hayas puesto en estas tablas, guardando los registros eliminados en el correspondiente LOG.